# How to write CSS selector for this page?

Tags: html, css

I try to set background of h2, h3, h4 tags that exist into div tag with Container3_title class .I use this selector but all of h2, h3, h4 tags that exist into page changed. Please advice

css:__________________________________________________

```
  div.Container3_title > h2, h3, h4, h5  {
            background: rgba(177, 49, 49, 0) url("images/nb-dots.png") repeat scroll 0% 0%;
        }
```

html :________________________________________________

```
<div class="Container3_body SpacingBottom">
    <div class="Container3_title">
        <h3>
            <span id="dnn_ctr428_dnnTITLE_titleLabel" class="Head">Text/HTML</span>



        </h3>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div id="dnn_ctr428_ContentPane"><!-- Start_Module_428 --><div id="dnn_ctr428_ModuleContent" class="DNNModuleContent ModDNNHTMLC">
    <div id="dnn_ctr428_HtmlModule_lblContent" class="Normal">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;"><span style="background-color: #fac08f;">افزودن محتوا...</span></h3>
<p style="margin-right: 40px;"><em><span style="background-color: #dbe5f1;"><br />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</span> <span style="text-decoration: underline;"> </span></em><span style="text-decoration: underline;"> </span></p>
<h3><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><em><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><br />
</span></em></span></h3>
<span style="background-color: #00b050;"> </span><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="background-color: #00b050;"> </span><em><span style="background-color: #00b050;">&nbsp;جمعه, 29 آبان 1394</span><br />
</em></span>
</div>

</div><!-- End_Module_428 --></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div></div>




    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="dnn_leftPane" class="col-lg-8   DNNEmptyPane"></div>
        <div id="dnn_sidebarPane" class="col-lg-4 sidebar "><div class="DnnModule DnnModule-DNN_HTML DnnModule-417"><a name="417"></a>



<div class="Container7_body SpacingBottom">
<div class="Container7_title">
    <h4>
        <span id="dnn_ctr417_dnnTITLE_titleLabel" class="Head">تیتر مطلب</span>



        <span class="clip"></span>
    </h4>
</div>


    <br />
    <div id="dnn_ctr417_ContentPane"><!-- Start_Module_417 --><div id="dnn_ctr417_ModuleContent" class="DNNModuleContent ModDNNHTMLC">
    <div id="dnn_ctr417_HtmlModule_lblContent" class="Normal">
    <p>در این کتاب آموزشی با برنامه نویسی وب با Dart آشنا می شوید.<br />
این کتاب&nbsp;آموزشی محصول موسسه Apress می باشد.</p>
<p>سرفصل های کتاب:</p>
<ul>
    <li>آغاز به کار برنامه</li>
    <li>راه اندازی Dart</li>
    <li>کار با ابزارها در Dart</li>
    <li>کار با ویرایشگر در Dart</li>
    <li>بهینه سازی برای DartVM و Dartium</li>
    <li>کار با&nbsp;نرم افزار کاربردی</li>
    <li>مبانی&nbsp;Dart</li>
    <li>کار با&nbsp;اپراتورها</li>
    <li>کار با&nbsp;انواع داده ها</li>
    <li>کار با توابع</li>
    <li>استثنا در پردازش و کنترل خطا</li>
    <li>کار با کلاس Dart</li>
    <li>پیاده سازی های عمومی و Typedefs</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is your selector.  You have this

```
div.Container3_title > h2, h3, h4, h5
```

Each comma `,` represents a new selector.  Instead you want to target each heading selector inside the parent container.

To do this you need to define the container for each one.

```
div.Container3_title h2,
div.Container3_title h3,
div.Container3_title h4,
div.Container3_title h5 { 
  background: rgba(177, 49, 49, 0) url("images/nb-dots.png") repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
```

The `>` you are using represents a direct child selector.

**The difference is**

`.parent > .child` will only select immediate children (one level deep) of the `.parent`

`.parent .child` will select all `.child` elements inside of the `.parent`.

Comment: OK.This is a nice answer